# How to show webcam capture in Plone site using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, plone

I am using Plone 4.3. I am trying to create a face recognition system on the Plone site. I need to show webcam captures using a template page. My sample code is below.  However, when I run this code, I can't get the captured image in the template file.

sample.py:

```
class video(BrowserView):
 video=ViewPageTemplateFile('video.pt')
 def chow(self):
   return self.video()
 def show_video(self):
  import cv2.cv as cv
  cv.NamedWindow("camera", 1)
  capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
  while True:
     img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
  return img
```

video.pt:

```
<div id="res">
 <!--Here face is url name-->
 <img id="draw" tal:attributes="src python:context.absolute_url() + '/face'">
 <!--the above line refers to call a method of show_video()-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good starting point: http://plone.org/products/collective.takeaportrait (activate the optional OpenCV integration).

Keep in mind that there's a **big** difference between showing the camera output on the screen (that is simply HTML 5) and performing face recognition server side.

Comment: how to get canvas image from browser to python